# Let a and b be positive integers and suppose that, for every positive integer c, we have that $a\equiv b\pmod c$. Then, $a=b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

Let c be any positive integer. Suppose $a\equiv b\pmod c$. Then, $c\mid b-a$.

Now what? I feel like I only have one tool at my disposal, namely divisibility: to say that $c\mid b-a$ means that $\exists d \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $b-a = cd$. But how do we go about showing that $a=b$ from here?

Comment: Wow, $5$ answers already. Maybe this question sets a record for the most answers :)

Comment: **HInt** $\ b-a\,$ is an integer with unbounded divisors $c,\,$ so $\, b-a = 0\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you hypothesis you have $a=b \pmod b =0 \pmod b$, so $a=kb$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$. But also $a=b \pmod a$ id est $b=a \pmod a=0 \pmod a$, so $b=k'a$ where $k' \in \mathbb{N}$. So finally $a = kk'a$, so $k=k'=1$, so $a=b$.

Comment: An elegant proof!

Answer (score 2):

WLOG, we can assume that $a\leq b$ because otherwise we can just switch $a$ and $b$ and the given problem conditions and the statement to be proven remains the same.

Now, taking $c=b$ gives you $a\equiv b\equiv 0\pmod b$, i.e.,  $b\mid a\implies b\leq a$.

Conclude.

---

If we completely want to prove this without any WLOG assumptions, just take $c=a$ once and then $c=b$.

You'll get that $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$ and we know this happens iff $a=b$

Comment: So you can let $c=a$ or $c=b$ and still go on to prove a statement for ALL $c$? I guess my question is, does showing this works for two different values of $c$ prove that it works for all $c$?

Comment: @kanker7, the "works for all $c$" is not what you're proving, it's what you're given. You're just supposed to prove that $a=b$. Since the given congruence holds for all positive integers $c$, it suffices to take $c=a$ and $c=b$ to prove the statement we want to prove.

Comment: ahhh, yes that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

If we have $a\ne b$, we can choose a number $c$ with $c>|a-b|$. Then, $c$ cannot divide $a-b$, completing the proof.

Answer (score 1):

This implies $a-b$ is divisible by every positive integer, which is impossible: it can't be divisible  by a number greater than itself – unless it is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$a\equiv b\pmod c$ for all $c$ if and only if $(a-b)=cN_c$  for all $c$ where $N_c$ is an integer. It is clear then that $a-b=0\iff a=b$